# Where does dependency User[root] (has failures) arise in Puppet manifest

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

The following Puppet manifest is meant for installing a binary and a systemd service description file, for starting the binary as a service, and for restarting the service when either the binary or the service description changes.

```
class my_module::my_service {

  file { '/usr/local/bin/my_service':
    notify => Service['my_service'],
    owner  => root,
    group  => root,
    mode   => '500',
    ensure => present,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/my_module/my_service',
  }

  file { '/lib/systemd/system/my_service.service':
    notify => Service['my_service'],
    owner  => root,
    group  => root,
    mode   => '400',
    ensure => present,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/my_module/my_service.service',
  }

  service { 'my_service':
    require  => [ File['/usr/local/bin/my_service'],
                  File['/lib/systemd/system/my_service.service'] ],
    enable   => true,
    ensure   => running,
    provider => systemd,
  }
}
```

When I try to apply it, I receive the following error messages:

```
Warning: /Stage[main]/My_module::My_service/File[/usr/local/bin/my_service]: 
Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/My_module::My_service/File[/lib/systemd/system/my_service.service]: 
Dependency User[root] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/My_module::My_service/File[/lib/systemd/system/my_service.service]: 
Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/My_module::My_service/Service[my_service]: 
Dependency User[root] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/My_module::My_service/Service[my_service]: 
Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

Where does the dependency on `User[root]` arise in this manifest and how can I resolve the resulting problem? (It seems to me that even if the `file`s' citations of `root` caused an implicit dependency on `User[root]` this special user should already exist in any case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was that I ran `puppet agent -f` from an unprivileged account. Adding `sudo` solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really avoid such implicit relationships. Your catalog tries to manage the root user, and if that fails, Puppet will refuse to touch dependent resources.

You should either find out why the `User[root]` resource fails in the first place (this is a major red flag, certainly), or if possible, stop managing that resource (it's usually indeed pointless to manage this very account).

Comment: What do you mean by the catalog failing to manage the root user?

Comment: @rookie09 Puppet runs into an error with a given resource (according to your answer, it was a permissions issue), so it marks it as failed. This state is not negotiable.